# performance issue with Workstation pro and enabling VT on Dell XPS 17

Tags: virtualization, vmware, vmware-workstation, dell-xps, vt-x

I recently moved from MAC to this very beefy CPS laptop with 64gb of ram and i9 12k processor.

However, I noticed a dramatic performance reduction when I moved my VMs from MAC to windows.

I decided to create brand-new VMs (windows) but the performance issue still exists

More important, I cannot activate any of the below (when activated, the VM won't turn on and will give an error):

- Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT (my processor is intel and the VT technology already enabled in the BIOS)
- Virtualize CPU performance counter
- Virtualize IOMMU

will really appreciate if anyone can shed light

Thanks

Comment: What are the guests in those virtual machines (OS and CPU)? I also don't have any problem with enabling "Virtualize Intel VT-x/EPT" and "Virtualize CPU performance counter". I don't see "Virtualize IOMMU".

Comment: I am confused, VT technology and VT-x are the same thing, so how you have difficulty enabling something that’s already enabled?

Comment: If you can't activate those features in WS, either Hyper-V or something else is already using the hardware virtualization, could be WSL, Windows Sandbox, or a number of other features in Windows 10/11.

Comment: excellent point, but how can i find out what is using the hardware virtualization @essjae?

Comment: I enabled the VT in bios of the laptop but cannot enable it (aka USE it) in the vmware's VMs @Ramhound

Comment: That means you have software installed and using it that’s preventing the software you want to use from using it. If VT-X, then hardware virtualization is enabled, so you will have to identify the unwanted software and uninstall it so VMWare can use hardware virtualization

Comment: If you just check the first option "virtualize intel vt-x" and don't use the other 2, you should be able to run your VMs at full speed without needing to mess around.  I have a Win11 laptop and can use the first option and run VMs at speed and also have WSL2 installed.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, for anyone else having this issue, this is the fix:

After confirming VT is enabled in BIOS, then:

1. Verify Virtualization-based Security (VBS) is Enabled/Not Enabled:

   1. Open msinfo32/System Information on Windows 10
   2. Under System Summary on the Right-hand page, scroll down to Virtualization-based Security and ensure the Value is set to Not enabled.
2. If the value is set to Enabled, follow the steps given below.

   1. Edit group policy (gpedit.msc)
   2. Go to Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System
   3. Double Click on Device Guard on the right hand side to open.
   4. Double Click on "Turn On Virtualization Security" to open a new window
   5. It would be "Not Configured", Select "Disable" and click "Ok"
   6. Close the Group Policy Editor.
   7. Restart the system
3. Turn Off Hyper-V

   1. Go to "Turn Windows features on or off"
   2. Make sure Hyper-v is not ticked.
   3. If it is Ticked, untick it and click "Ok".
4. Open command prompt window as an administrator

   1. Run `bcdedit /enum {current}`
   2. Note down the hypervisorlaunchtype in case this needs to be reverted
   3. Run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` to disable hypervisor Close the command prompt after   executing the commands and restart the system.
5. Also make sure that Memory Integrity is set to OFF under Windows Security -> Device Security -> Core Isolation.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).